# CRSF Token is missing or incorrect

Tags: django, django-forms

I am getting a 403 forbidden error. i have tried doing the context thingie that has been explained on the forum, but i am still at square one.

What am i doing wrong? my views.py

```
def add_player(request, team_id):
    template = get_template('cricket/addplayer.html')
    loggedinuser = request.user
    team = Team.objects.get(id=team_id)
    if request.method== 'POST':
        form = PlayerForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            player = Player.objects.create(
                name = form.cleaned_data['name'],
                team = Team.objects.get(id=team_id),
                role = form.cleaned_data['role'],
                position = form.cleaned_data['position']
            )

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/team/%s/' % team_id)
    else:
        form = PlayerForm

    page_vars = Context({
        'form': form,
        'loggedinuser': loggedinuser,
        'team': team,
    })

    output = template.render(page_vars)
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

and my template. as you can see, it has got the {% csrf_token %}

```
{% extends 'cricket/base.html' %}
{% block title %}
    {{ loggedinuser }}
{% endblock %}

{% block username %}
    {{ loggedinuser }}
{% endblock %}

{% block date %}
    {{ today }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="span7">
        <h2>Adding player for {{ team }}</h2>
        <form method="post" action=".">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

i am pretty sure i would hack my head off something pretty soon.

//mouse

Okey i solved it. you have to use RequestContext. here is my solution, change the final two lines in the orignal code to include crsfcontext

```
page_vars = Context({
    'form': form,
    'loggedinuser': loggedinuser,
    'team': team,
})

crsfcontext = RequestContext(request, page_vars)

output = template.render(crsfcontext)
return HttpResponse(output)
```

Comment: Hi mouse, glad you solved your problem. Rather than editing your question to include your solution, it's better if you add it as a separate answer. That way other users can vote it up, and you can mark it as accepted, which lets other users see that you've found the answer.

Comment: You can use [render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) for more clean code in the view

Comment: i could not answer my own question, had to wait 8 hours.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a class based generic view in django.
Could be something like this in your case: (I have not test it)

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^your-url/(?P<teamId>\d+)/$', AddPlayerView.as_view(), name="add-player"),
)
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import FormView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
 .....

class AddPlayerView(FormView):

    template_name = 'cricket/addplayer.html'
    form_class = PlayerForm 

    def form_valid(self, form):
    """ Code if the form is valid """
                ...
        player = Player.objects.create(
            name = form.cleaned_data['name'],
            team = Team.objects.get(id=form.cleaned_data['team_id']),
            role = form.cleaned_data['role'],
            position = form.cleaned_data['position']
        )

        # You could use url reverse here
        url = reverse('your-view-name', args=[form.cleaned_data['team_id']])
        return HttpResponseRedirect(url)


    def form_invalid(self, form):
    """ Code if the form is invalid """
        .....


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AddPlayerView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        loggedinuser = self.request.user
        team = Team.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['teamId'])
        context['loggedinuser'] = loggedinuser
        context['team'] = team
        return context
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use render_to_response function instead of HttpResponse with some RequestContext.